# How to show that for $n$ sufficiently large, relative to $k$, $(n+1)(n+2) \ldots (n+k)$ is divisible by at least $k$ distinct primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I would like to show that $\displaystyle \frac{(n+k)!}{n!}$ is divisible by at least $k$ distinct primes whenever $n$ is sufficiently large.  We all know that it is divisible by $k!$ and hence by $\displaystyle \pi(k) \sim \frac{k}{\ln k}$ distinct primes, but it appears one can do much better than this.  I am told that this follows from some deeper results from Baker, (that in fact one can show this is divisible by at least $k-1+\pi(k)$ distinct primes when $n$ is sufficiently large), but I am curious whether someone can see an elementary way to show the weaker result I am asking for.